# Send_data not sending pdf (WickedPdf)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf for a user to download. i'm using the WickedPdf gem.

```
<%= simple_form_for :report, url: [:download, :admin, :reports], format: :pdf, method: :get, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :event, collection: @events %> 
  <%= f.input :report_type, collection: [:schedule, :overview] %>
  <%= f.submit "Download" %>
<% end %>



class Admin::ReportsController < Admin::BaseController

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def download
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_string)
        send_data pdf, :filename => "report.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def pdf_string
    render_to_string(template:'admin/reports/pdf/schedule_overview.html.erb', layout: false)
  end

end
```

app/views/admin/reports/pdf/schedule_overview.html.erb

```
This is a pdf
```

(just text atm)

Server when request is made:

```
Started GET "/admin/reports/download?utf8=%E2%9C%93&report%5Bevent%5D=1&report%5Breport_type%5D=schedule&commit=Download" for ::1 at 2017-08-16 16:18:49 +0100
Processing by Admin::ReportsController#download as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "report"=>{"event"=>"1", "report_type"=>"schedule"}, "commit"=>"Download"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering admin/reports/pdf/schedule_overview.html.erb
  Rendered admin/reports/pdf/schedule_overview.html.erb (0.8ms)
"***************[\"/Users/jonathansayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf\", \"-q\", \"file:////var/folders/0x/g3xdsy4s48q9y0lpzsppltv80000gn/T/wicked_pdf20170816-33407-4r72d4.html\", \"/var/folders/0x/g3xdsy4s48q9y0lpzsppltv80000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20170816-33407-1hnp6hr.pdf\"]***************"
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.1ms)
Sent data report.pdf (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1803ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms))
```

But no pdf is sent to the client. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess format should be `pdf` not `js`

Comment: Yes, updated. But still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: can you show your updated code?

Comment: Done @PardeepDhingra

Comment: `simple_form` format has typo

Comment: `<%= simple_form_for :report, url: [:download, :admin, :reports], format: :pdf, method: :get, remote: true do |f| %>`

Comment: Yep, sorry. That was my rushed typing. Updated but still the same issue.

Comment: Try in different browsers. On Microsoft EDGE, sometimes PDF don't open..

Comment: Tried on Chrome and Safari, still no download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by removing `remote: true`